# Function Components or Class Components for React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I always get answers for React JS answered in functional style. Does it mean that class style of coding React JS is no longer supported or right to be used?

I took up React JS through class coding style and I have always loved it that way, I think that ditching it for functional based components (which doesn't interest me) will add an overhead to my learning curve. Actually, I love coding in classes from my OOP coding style origin. So, that's why I detest functional React JS style. Is it something I must adopt?

If I declare a class based state for several properties like this:

```
    state = {contextData : {
        loginRequestData : {
            userName : "",
            password : ""
        },
        loginButtonParts : {
            buttonTitle : "Log In",
            buttonClass : this.visibleButtonClass
        },
        inputValidity : {
            userNameValidity : {
                userNameValid : false,
                messageLayout : this.hiddenErrorMessage,
                errorMessage : this.userNameEmptyError
            }, 
            passwordValidity : {
                passwordValid : false,
                messageLayout : this.hiddenErrorMessage,
                errorMessage : this.passwordEmptyError
            },
            credentialValidity : {
                messageLayout : this.hiddenErrorMessage,
                errorMessage : this.incorrectCredentialError
            }
        }
    }};
```

and I want to setState for one of the properties only, say buttonClass. This is what I do:

```
this.setState(function(state) {
        return {contextData : {
            loginRequestData : state.contextData.loginRequestData,
            loginButtonParts : {
                buttonTitle : state.contextData.loginButtonParts.buttonTitle,
                buttonClass : this.hiddenButtonClass
            },
            inputValidity : state.contextData.inputValidity     
        }
    }});
```

Is it the simplest way to do it for class based component or is there a more concise way to reduce the boilerplate code?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

In my opinion, functional components are better than class based components. It's easier and simpler to adapt to. Solutions to most problems were resolved in functional components and most third party libraries favor functions over classes.

Comment: yep, that will do ! of course no one can say that class based components are dead, but today if company decides to use React.js, its 90% functional components because it is easier to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Function components with Hooks are generally recommended due to their simplicity and the additional capabilities provided by Hooks. If you are creating new project then you can go with functional component.  Otherwise choice is yours (as per your requirement).

Here is another way to do this

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const contextData = { ...prevState.contextData };
  contextData.loginButtonParts.buttonClass = this.visibleButtonClass;
  return { contextData };
});
```